# Picker in Menu with Section and Label doesn't work

Tags: swiftui

The following code shows different Pickers.

I want to achieve: **MenuPickerStyle with Sections and custom Label** like in second example https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7JFD.jpg but it is not selectable because it is grayed out

When doing it with the Menu container as recommended in the internet the rows are grayed out. How can I get the wanted behavior?

In the code you can see 4 different examples. The second is the grayed out picker rows.

Tested in Xcode 13.2.1, iOS 15

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State var number_1 = 0
    @State var number_2 = 0
    @State var number_3 = 0
    @State var number_4 = 0
    let numbers = [0,1,2,3,4]
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            //Picker works, no Section --------------------------
            Menu(content: {
                Picker(selection: $number_1, content: {
                    ForEach(numbers,id: \.self){i in
                        Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
                    }
                }, label: {EmptyView()})
            }, label: {
                Text("selected Number = \(number_1)")
            })
            
            //Picker is grayed out ---------------------------
            Menu(content: {
                Picker(selection: $number_2, content: {
                    ForEach(numbers,id: \.self){i in
                        Section{
                            Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
                        }
                    }
                }, label: {EmptyView()})
            }, label: {
                Text("selected Number = \(number_2)")
            })
            
            //Picker works, collapsed View not desired behavior --------
            Menu(content: {
                Picker(selection: $number_3, content: {
                    ForEach(numbers,id: \.self){i in
                        Section{
                            Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
                        }
                    }
                }, label: {EmptyView()})
                    .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            }, label: {
                Text("selected Number = \(number_3)")
            })
            
            //Picker Works, label not ----------------------------
            Picker(selection: $number_4, content: {
                ForEach(numbers,id: \.self){i in
                    Section{
                        Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
                    }
                }
            }, label: {Text("selected Number = \(number_4)")})
                .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())

        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what do you try to achieve... submenu? Would you provide some demo screenshot or sketch?

Comment: I would like to have like the first example a picker as a menu but with a custom label. But if I add a section inside the picker the rows are grayed out like in the second example. Why is it grayed out?

Comment: Did you try to invert ForEach and Section ?

Comment: Yes, should be the same problem

Comment: @Asperi added image for desired design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put multiple Pickers in a Menu, each with a subset of the available values, and they’ll all work as expected:

```
Menu {

    // First section, with values 0–2
    Picker(selection: $num) {
        ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { i in
            Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
        }
    } label: {
        EmptyView()
    }

    // Second section, with values 3–5
    Picker(selection: $num) {
        ForEach(3..<6, id: \.self) { i in
            Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
        }
    } label: {
        EmptyView()
    }

} label: {
    Text("selected Number = \(num)")
}
```

SwiftUI will even stick a separator between the Pickers automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is for case 4 - just rebuild menu (force-refresh) on selection changed:

```
        //Picker Works, label not ----------------------------
        Picker(selection: $number_4, content: {
            ForEach(numbers,id: \.self){i in
                Section{
                    Text("Number: \(i)").tag(i)
                }
            }
        }, label: {Text("selected Number = \(number_4)")})
        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
        .id(number_4)                    // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Comment: With Xcode 13.2.1 the label is still "Number: x". Could it be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a workaround.
I tried to use a menu and use Buttons for manipulating the selection. The problem is the mark of the selection if there is already a Image in the label of the button I think.

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @State var number = 0
    let numbers = [1,2,3,4]
    var body: some View{
        Menu(content: {
            ForEach(numbers,id:\.self){i in
                Section{
                    Button(action: {
                        number = i
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Number: \(i)")
                    })
                }
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("The selection is: \(number)")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 20)
                .border(Color.green)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add `.id(number)` the animation in the text selection can be deactivated: why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand, but if your goal is to build a picker that lets the user click on the title and then select an option from a menu, returning the selection to the screen I would suggest doing it as follows:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @State var option:Int = 0
    let numbers = [1,2,3,4]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
           //Picker to select the option
            Picker("Option Picker", selection: $option) {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) {
                    number in
                    Text("Selection Number \(number)").tag(number)
                }
 
            }.pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            
            //Text confirming the selection won't show before a pick is made
            Text(option != 0 ? "You selected option number \(option)" : "")
  
        }
            
        
                    
    }
}
```

Let me know if that works for you / is what you were looking for.